# Use the definition of the derivative of a vector to find scalar triple product.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

How to find $(u(t)v(t)×w(t))'$ by using definition of the derivative of a vector.
I only know how to find $(u(t)v(t))'$ or $(v(t)×w(t))'$

Comment: The "product rule" is valid both for scalar and vector products, for instance the derivative of $u(t)\times v(t)$ is $u'(t)\times v(t)+u(t)\times v'(t)$, etc.

Comment: @Wan, Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, read this: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

With implicit summation over repeated indices,$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}(u\cdot v\times w)&=\frac{d}{dt}(\epsilon_{ijk}u_iv_jw_k)\\&=\epsilon_{ijk}u^\prime_iv_jw_k+\epsilon_{ijk}u_iv^\prime_jw_k+\epsilon_{ijk}u_iv_jw^\prime_k\\&=u^\prime\cdot v\times w+u\cdot v^\prime\times w+u\cdot v\times w^\prime,\end{align}$$where the second $=$ uses the product rule.